# ERROR: column "urls" is of type url[] but expression is of type record[]

Tags: postgresql

ddl

```
CREATE TYPE url AS (
    url varchar,
    status int4);


CREATE TABLE public.tiantang_page (
    href varchar NOT NULL,
    status int4 NOT NULL,
    description varchar NOT NULL,
    urls url[] NULL,
    urltest url NULL
);
```

sql

```
INSERT INTO public.tiantang_page
(href, status, description, urls, urltest)
VALUES('', 0, '', array[row('test',0)], row('test',0));
```

error

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "urls" is of type url[] but expression is of type record[]
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error message, you'll need to cast back to your composite `url` type using `::`

```
INSERT INTO public.tiantang_page
(href, status, description, urls, urltest)
VALUES('', 0, '', array[row('test',0)::url], row('test',0)::url);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/31f4b/1)